# Enabling standard emoticons on Android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I can enable emoticons on the android keyboard for a `TextView` by adding

```
android:inputType="textShortMessage"
```

However, I get the android emoticons (which I think are really ugly), instead of the standard emoticons that you get on iOS and what WhatsApp has on Android. Is there any way to programmatically change the emoticons to the standard ones?

Comment: `I get the android emoticons (which I think are really ugly), instead of the standard emoticons that you get on iOS and what WhatsApp has on Android. Is there any way to programmatically change the emoticons to the standard ones?`. **NO**, because the `really ugly` ones actually **are the standard ones**. WhatsApp (and Telegram) use **non standard** emoticons. And, **YES**, you can use them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of android keyboard emojis you can open custom emoji's keyboard that deals in emoji characters code .You can find library of that easily.Few are:

> https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon
>
> https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard
>
> https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon